# Why does this wiring for double audio output not work?

Tags: audio

I tried to connect two different audio jacks to the same guitar pickup. One I connected to my PC through a USB interface and the other to an amp. Neither output produced any sound. Is there something wrong with this layout in theory?

[image]

Comment: Which USB interface? What happened if you unplugged one of them?

Comment: Not complete solution, but for the starting point: add two capacitors (10uF ?), inline/series with the (+) wiring of each load (computer, amp). At the computer/amplifier (load) end, add a shunt-s (4.7k ?,  thus two of). That is the starting point.

Comment: One suggestion for doing this in a more end-user method is a Direct Input (DI) box. It will have a passthrough to connect the amp as usual, but also a balanced output to then connect to your audio interface.